# Need to make the below sql query to automatically go to Month n (last paid) from the beginning (open_date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the current query I have to specify Month 0, Month 1, Month 2, Mopnth 3... up to Month 18.  as you can see Is there any way to modify this query such that It automatically calculates the month difference between the date paid and the open date and then populates the column with the sum of payment amount in that month. SO It will not be limited to 18 Month and keeps automatically create and populate the value till Month n without specifying Months.

```
SELECT        
[loan_number], 
acctrefno, 
open_date/*FORMAT(CAST(op.open_date as date), 'yyyy-MM') AS year_month,*/ 
, [Month -1] = IsNull([-1], 0)
, [Month 0] = IsNull([0], 0)
, [Month 1] = IsNull([1], 0)
, [Month 2] = IsNull([2], 0), 
    [Month 3] = IsNull([3], 0)
     , [Month 4] = IsNull([4], 0)
     , [Month 5] = IsNull([5], 0)
         , [Month 6] = IsNull([6], 0)
         , [Month 7] = IsNull([7], 0)
         , [Month 8] = IsNull([8], 0)
         , [Month 9] = IsNull([9], 0)
         , [Month 10] = IsNull([10], 0)
         , [Month 11] = IsNull([11],  0)
         , [Month 12] = IsNull([12], 0), [Month 13] = IsNull([13], 0), [Month 14] = IsNull([14], 0), [Month 15] = IsNull([15], 0), [Month 16] = IsNull([16], 0), [Month 17] = IsNull([17], 0), [Month 18] = IsNull([18], 0)
/*,[Month 70] = IsNull([70],0)*/ 

FROM 
(SELECT       
 L.loan_number
 , l.acctrefno/*, FORMAT(CAST(l.open_date as date), 'yyyy-MM') AS open_date*/ 
 , format(cast(l.open_date AS date), 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-US') AS open_date/*, */ , 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Item = DateDiff(WEEK, [open_date], [datepaid]), Value = [tot_receipts]
                                                                               
     FROM  
     [NLS].[dbo].loanacct L 
     INNER JOIN
     [NLS].[dbo].[loanacct_detail] LD1 ON LD1.acctrefno = L.acctrefno 
     LEFT JOIN
    [NLS].[dbo].OwnPayments_2 OP ON L.acctrefno = OP.acctrefno
 WHERE        /*p(ayment_type = 'zz' or payment_type IS NULL) AND */ L.portfolio_code_id = 11/*AND l.loan_type = 0*/ ) src 
 PIVOT (sum(Value) FOR Item IN ([-1], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], 
                         [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18])) pvt
```

Comment: Unless you use dynamic sql, no. Think about what you're asking; columns of a resultset are like properties of an object. They don't dynamically change from time to time. Your car doesn't have air conditioning one day and not the next, but cruise control the day after, then 2 days later it gets swapped for a moon roof. Why is it important that columns don't change dynamically? Because typically the front end has to be recompiled to cope with that.. You're trying to do in the back end what is really the front end's job; the database should provide rows, the front end should crosstab/pivot them

Comment: Thank you for your inforamation.